# How to extract <A> Tag using GuzzleHttp on Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi I have laravel project using the GuzzleHttp to get A tag list. I can get body as below code

```
class GuzzleController extends Controller
{
public function Index(){
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();        
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://google.com');
    if($response->getStatusCode() == 200){
        $body = $response->getBody();
        return $body;
    }else{
        return "fail";
    }
   }
}
```

But I have no idea how to extract list of A Tag from response. Thanks for all answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). For example:

```
use DOMDocument;

class GuzzleController extends Controller
{
    public function Index(){
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();        
        $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://google.com');

        $html = (string) $response->getBody(); 

        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($html);

        $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

        foreach ($links as $link){
            echo $link->nodeValue;
            echo $link->getAttribute('href');
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example. Ideally, you would want to inject those dependencies.

Comment: I got an error 'App\Http\Controllers\DOMDocument' not found

Comment: You need to add `use DOMDocument` at the top :)